# Not able to setup the keycloak using Docker

Tags: java, docker, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Following is my docker file:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
services:
  keycloak:
    image: 'quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy'
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: localhost
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: mypassword
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: myadminpassword
      JAVA_OPTS_APPEND: '-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled'
    ports:
      - '8181:8080'
    expose:
      - '80'
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
```

When running this docker, it is starting but then keep restart with following errors:

```
07:16:33,781 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:364)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:371)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1328)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:505)
    
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    ... 67 more

07:16:33,784 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@19.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:420)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@19.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@19.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@19.0.3//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:751)

07:16:33,787 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
07:16:33,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
07:16:33,800 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
07:16:33,802 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
07:16:33,807 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8443
07:16:33,808 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = mysql
07:16:33,811 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ejb`
07:16:33,813 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ejb`
07:16:33,814 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ejb`
07:16:33,956 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,958 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.ThemeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.error.KcUnrecognizedPropertyExceptionHandler from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.JsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RealmsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.WelcomeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002210: Adding provider singleton org.keycloak.services.util.ObjectMapperResolver from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RobotsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:33,959 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
07:16:34,012 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.23.Final
07:16:34,023 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) RESTEASY008550: Unable to find CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using default ValidatorFactory
07:16:34,097 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
07:16:34,099 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/auth' from server 'default-server'
07:16:34,101 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow AJP listener ajp suspending
07:16:34,101 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
07:16:34,101 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow AJP listener ajp stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8009
07:16:34,102 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) MODCLUSTER000002: Initiating mod_cluster shutdown
07:16:34,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
07:16:34,106 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
07:16:34,106 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8080
07:16:34,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
07:16:34,111 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ejb`
07:16:34,116 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
07:16:34,117 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.2.17.Final stopping
07:16:34,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 334ms
07:16:34,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authorization cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped keys cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped users cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,128 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped realms cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineSessions cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authenticationSessions cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped clientSessions cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped loginFailures cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped actionTokens cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped work cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,138 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped sessions cache from keycloak container
07:16:34,141 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel `ejb`
07:16:34,150 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "metrics")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.extension.metrics@26.1.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.metrics.MetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MetricsSubsystemAdd.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1045)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:777)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:466)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1427)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:559)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:572)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:534)
    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:470)
    at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:414)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@18.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:473)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

07:16:34,156 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
07:16:34,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 19.0.3 (WildFly Core 18.1.1.Final) stopped in 386ms
User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'
Oct 20, 2023 7:17:09 AM org.keycloak.common.crypto.CryptoIntegration detectProvider
INFO: Detected crypto provider: org.keycloak.crypto.def.DefaultCryptoProvider
User with username 'admin' already added to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json'
```

I have checked the DB credentials and it is working fine. Other docker using the same credential is able to connect to db.

also even after the DB connection failure in the docker, it is continuing to the next step and failing with "`: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "metrics")]): java.lang.NullPointerException`"

Can anyone let me know what could be the issue? I am struggling for last 2 days.

Thanks